# iTunes Connect account expiring: what are the consequences for my app?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

My iTunes Connect account is expiring next months. Does this mean I can't update my app anymore ? Or does it mean my app will be removed from the app store ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once Your account is expired
1.You can't update your app any more.
2.It will be removed from the appstore until you renew your accoint

Comment: How much does it the renewal of iTunes connect cost? Sorry I couldn't find this info, without a membership to the Apple website.